# Problems using 'usnchanged' to poll for AD changes (Powershell)

Tags: powershell-2.0

I have been writing an interface for product called SuccessFactors and I'm having issues with a component of it.

Part of the script is a simple AD Extract, however, I am using a previous highestCommittedUSN from adrootdse to only extract changes (rather than a complete AD Extract).

The relevant lines are shown below;

```
$dse = get-adrootdse
$ou = @('**various OU's**')
$activedirectory = $ou | ForEach { Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties * -SearchBase $_ }
$oldadtimestamp = Get-Content ".\adtimestamp.txt"
$adusers = $activedirectory | where {$_.usnchanged -gt $oldadtimestamp} | foreach {$_}
$dse.highestCommittedUSN > adtimestamp.txt
```

I then run through $adusers and output the relevant data to an array which is exported to a csv outside of the loop.

The problem I'm having is this; if I perform multiple extracts throughout the day, it works correctly. However, if I leave it for a weekend and run the script, I'm getting an empty CSV OR a complete AD Extract. There seems to be no pattern to it.

Am I doing something obviously wrong?

Many Thanks,
Tom

Comment: Can you explain why are you creating this in regards to SuccessFactors?

Answer (score 0):

Target a single DC not the whole domain. Each DC has a different highestcommittedUSN

Try

```
$dse = get-adrootdse -Server <ServerName>
```